# Making XY Event Layer into Copy Feature layer using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, feature-layer, data-management

I am taking a CSV file and importing it with the XY Event feature layer.  I then am trying to use the Copy Feature tool to get "Object ID" assigned to each row in order to run an attribute query.  My issues is that I can't get the Copy Feature layer to work properly.  I believe that the issue is with the feature class I am trying to make using the tool.

I am new to python and can't seem to get this to work right.  I am sure I have other issues with my code, but one step at a time.

When I do the try/expect the code works till the copy features layer, so I know that is probably my first of many issues.

```
#Import a CSV file that will show you what ASOS weather stations are in the state.
import arcpy
import os 

#Lets you write over the shape file if needed
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

arcpy.env.workspace = "C:\\GEOG485\\FinalProject"
#Latitude and Longitude Coordinates 
xFieldName = 'LON'
yFieldName = 'LAT'

#Output folder
outFolder = "C:\\GEOG485\\FinalProject\\Output"

#ASOS stations layer
eventLayer = "ASOS"
outPutlayer = "CurrentStations.shp"

#Spatial Reference
spatialRef = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)

#CSV file that will be imported into ArcMap
csvFilePath = "C:\\GEOG485\\FinalProject\\isd-history.csv"

#Select state of interest
targetState = 'NJ'

#Date of file last updated
targetEnd = '20190329'


try:
    #import csv file using the xy event layer tool
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(csvFilePath, xFieldName, yFieldName, eventLayer, spatialRef)

    #Copy features from the XY Event Layer in order to asign Object ID's to the rows in the file
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(eventLayer, outPutlayer)

    #Select Attribute management to narrow down the state of interest
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("currentasos", "NEW_SELECTION", '"STATE" = ' + "'" + targetState + "'")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("currentasos", "SUBSET_SELECTION", '"END" = ' + "'" + targetEnd + "'")
    print ("success")

except:
    print ("error")

try:
    mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument("C:\\GEOG485\\FinalProject\\basemap.mxd")
    df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrame(mxd, "*")[0]
    newLayer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("currentasos")
    arcpy.mapping.Layer(df, newLayer, "Bottom")
except:
    print ("error4")
```

Comment: Your try/except is masking a potentially useful error. Do line by line printing in between to see what the error is and update your question.

Comment: You're writing to a folder but also not giving a file extension. Either make your workspace a gdb or give the output from copy features a. shp extension

Comment: Is `success` (variable) defined somewhere? This will fail currently. If you want it to print the string "success", enclose in quotes.

Comment: So i assigned a shp extension, but still having the same problem with FID being assigned to the rows instead of OID.

Comment: Didn't catch that you were looking for objectid earlier. You need a feature class in a geodatabase for that. Shapefiles have FID. https://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010834

Comment: when i created the geodatabase that seemed to of worked and I was able to get the Object IDs assigned to the rows.  now I think i have to add a Make feature layer in order to run the attribute queries.

Comment: Yes, that is correct - SelectByAttributes uses a layer not a feature class. I'll incorporate my comments into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few syntax errors in your code. Overall, when testing out a new process be careful what you include in try/except blocks as they can mask helpful errors. When in doubt, remove it from the try/except and just do each line separately, printing each line (or `print(arcpy.GetMessages())` ) to see what errors occur and at what stage.

A few things of note:

You're writing to a folder but also not giving a file extension. Either use a GDB as your workspace or give the output from copy features a. shp extension. If you explicitly want ObjectIDs (featureclasses) vs FIDs (shapefiles), set your workspace to a geodatabase. http://support.esri.com/en/technical-article/000010834

On an earlier edit you had a line printing `success` (variable) - Is this defined somewhere? This would fail if not. To print the string "success", enclose in quotes.

Before performing SelectByAttributes, create a layer. In the current edit of the Question, there is a reference to a feature class "currentasos"; use `MakeFeatureLayer_management` to create a layer first, as this is required for SelectByAttributes.